# Neumann problem for two adjacent regions.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ are two adjacent regions with "smooth enough" (Lipschiz or piecewise smooth, I suppose?) boundary in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f$ a function in, say $L^2(\overline{\Omega} \cup \overline{\Omega'})$. When can you find a solution $u$ in, say $H^1(\overline{\Omega} \cup \overline{\Omega'})$ such that

$$\Delta u = f$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = 0$$
given that
$$\int_\Omega f = \int_{\Omega'} f = 0$$
for each $\nu$ the normal on the boundary of $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$?

For example, when can you solve it in the case where $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ are two adjacent squares of the same length or two concentric circles?

Edit: after some computation, if I am correct, I found that this almost never works for the case of concentric circles. It only works in a case when all the Fourier coefficients except possibly the $1, 2, -1, -2$'th Fourier coefficients are nonzero.

Comment: Smoothness and Lipschitz are conditions on *functions*. What do you mean by applying them to *regions*?

Comment: Boundaries are lipschitz: e.g. they are locally graphs of lipschitz functions.

Comment: Stated exactly as you have it, If $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ do not overlap, then for any $f$ (at all) for which solutions exist in both $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ separately, those solutions are the restriction to $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ of a solution on all of $\Omega \cup \Omega'$. This is because $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ are open, and therefore even their shared boundary is not part of their union. But I suspect what you are really after is a solution for $U = \Omega \cup \Omega' \cup (\partial \Omega \cap \partial\Omega')$, presuming $U$ is itself a region.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks. I'll change it.

Comment: Should change my version to $\text{Int}(\Omega \cup \Omega' \cup (\partial \Omega \cap \partial\Omega'))$, to avoid including things like the shared corners of your adjacent squares.